# TypeScript type definitions for ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, service-worker

I'm writing a service for my angular 2 app using TypeScript. The service makes use of chrome's `ServiceWorker` to listen for push notifications (see [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en)). The code (javascript) makes use of `navigator` first to see if `serviceWorker` is supported, then continues to complete registration etc., i.e.,

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log('Service Worker is supported');
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function() {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  }).then(function(reg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);
      // TODO
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Service Worker error :^(', error);
  });
}
```

I'd like to implemenet the above using TypeScript. However, the current `lib.d.ts` used by the TypeScript compiler (see below) appears to have no definitions defined on `Navigator` for the `serviceWorker` or its associated methods such as `serviceWorker.register` (I guess since it's a chrome-specific implementation).

```
interface Navigator extends Object, NavigatorID, NavigatorOnLine, NavigatorContentUtils, NavigatorStorageUtils, NavigatorGeolocation, MSNavigatorDoNotTrack, MSFileSaver, NavigatorUserMedia {
    readonly appCodeName: string;
    readonly cookieEnabled: boolean;
    readonly language: string;
    readonly maxTouchPoints: number;
    readonly mimeTypes: MimeTypeArray;
    readonly msManipulationViewsEnabled: boolean;
    readonly msMaxTouchPoints: number;
    readonly msPointerEnabled: boolean;
    readonly plugins: PluginArray;
    readonly pointerEnabled: boolean;
    readonly webdriver: boolean;
    getGamepads(): Gamepad[];
    javaEnabled(): boolean;
    msLaunchUri(uri: string, successCallback?: MSLaunchUriCallback, noHandlerCallback?: MSLaunchUriCallback): void;
    requestMediaKeySystemAccess(keySystem: string, supportedConfigurations: MediaKeySystemConfiguration[]): PromiseLike<MediaKeySystemAccess>;
    vibrate(pattern: number | number[]): boolean;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
}
```

The result is that I'm faced with compilation errors since the compiler can't find the associated `serviceWorker` types. Given I'm new to JavaScript and TypeScript, I'm trying to determine the best way to proceed. I understand the options to be:

1. Keep the js code and simply ignore the compilation errors (not
   ideal).
2. Keep the js code and somehow suppress the type errors during
       compilation.
3. Find an existing typescript definitions library that
       has `serviceWorker` defined and include that during compilation.
4. Write my own typescript definition file for navigator or somehow
       extend the existing `lib.d.ts`

Sage advice on the best option greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Attempted to cast to any to remove compilation errors, i.e.,

```
var nav = <any> navigator;

    if ('serviceWorker' in nav) {
       nav.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
           .then(function(reg) {
                    console.log('yey!', <any> reg);
           }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log('boo!', <any> err);
    });
```

but now facing new errors, i.e.,

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'reg' implicitly has an 'any' type.
error TS7006: Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Also, tempted to write definitions for the ServiceWorker using these [details](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#navigator-service-worker). However never done it before, so will need some practice!

Answer (score 6):

Type definitions for [ServiceWorker and friends](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#idl-index) are now available from [DefinitelyTyped/service_worker_api](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/HEAD/service_worker_api):

```
$ npm install --save @types/service_worker_api
```

Usage example:

```
// data-access.service.ts
/// <reference path="typings/globals/service_worker_api/index.d.ts" />
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataAccess {
    constructor() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', { scope: '/api/' });
    }
}
```

Adjust the paths as necessary.

Comment: As of TypeScript 2.0, `npm install --save @types/service_worker_api` [will also work](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

Comment: @mjs That is a very nice improvement.

Comment: The links are dead. Please update your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add to the interface in your TypeScript file and when the lib.d.ts is updated, the compiler will tell you that you no longer need it.

```
interface Navigator {
    getUserMedia(
        options: { video?: bool; audio?: bool; }, 
        success: (stream: any) => void, 
        error?: (error: string) => void
        ) : void;
}

navigator.getUserMedia(
    {video: true, audio: true}, 
    function (stream) {  },
    function (error) {  }
);
```

or

Instead of changing the definition you can cast to an `any` object an call with arbitray parameters e.g:

```
 var n = <any>navigator;
    n.getUserMedia  = n.getUserMedia || n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia || n.msGetUserMedia;
    return  n.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true}, onSuccess, onFail);
```

Comment: Casting would be the simplest solution, however attempted to cast to `<any>` gives error `TS7006: Parameter 'reg' implicitly has an 'any' type`. - see update.

Answer (score 2):

ServiceWorker is not a chrome specific extension.

OP should refer to Jake Archibald's [isSERVICEWORKERready?](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/) page for a rundown of the current state of ServiceWorker in the popular browsers.

I added the type definitions in `tsd.d.ts` based on the interface information [linked](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#service-worker-interface) by OP and they seem to be working.

**Please note** that I referenced `IPromise` interface from [angular.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts).

Defined in `tsd.d.ts`

```
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

interface Navigator {
    serviceWorker: ServiceWorkerContainer;
}

interface ServiceWorkerContainer {
  register(scriptUrl: string, options?: RegistrationOptions): angular.IPromise<ServiceWorkerRegistration>;
}

interface RegistrationOptions {
  scope: string;
}

interface ServiceWorkerRegistration {
  installing?: ServiceWorker;
  waiting?: ServiceWorker;
  active?: ServiceWorker;

  scope: string;

  update(): angular.IPromise<void>;
  unregister(): angular.IPromise<boolean>;
}

interface ServiceWorker {
  scriptUrl: string;
  state: string;

  postMessage(message: any, transfer: Array<any>): void;
}
```

Referred in `home-controller.ts`

```
///<reference path='../../typings/tsd.d.ts' />
...
// dependencies are injected via AngularJS $injector
constructor() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ctrlName = 'HomeCtrl';
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', { scope: '/' }).then(function(reg) {
      // registration worked
      console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // registration failed
      console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('serviceWorker not available in navigator.');
  }
}
```

Building and loading the app in the chrome

[image]

logs the following console message:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Original Answer**

Here are the Typings I created to use with WebStorm: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tiernan/11a40d253a55a5c5ff518d6deae3ee48).

Then in my service-worker.ts file I include a reference: `/// <reference path="YOUR_PATH_HERE/service-worker.d.ts" />`.

Adjust your path accordingly, or make them global and you should be pretty set. It's fairly complete, but I'm sure it's missing some things. Anyway, I hope this helps.

**2018 Update:**

I published a new edition of these definitions to work with lib.webworker.d.ts along with any es5+ library (lib.es5.d.ts, lib.es2015.d.ts, etc) here: [Service Worker Typings to Supplement lib.webworker.d.ts](https://gist.github.com/tiernan/c18a380935e45a6d942ac1e88c5bbaf3). This set should be much more relevant today.

Comment: This is great! Made a few (piecemeal) updates: https://gist.github.com/ithinkihaveacat/227bfe8aa81328c5d64ec48f4e4df8e5

Comment: @mjs Thanks for your contribution! I pulled your changes with some slight modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript does now provide an out-of-the-box solution.

Here is an example how you can make use of `jsdoc` in a vanilla `sw.js` files to get full intellisense and type checking for your service worker.

All it needs is the latest `typescript` npm module:

```
// @ts-check
/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
(/** @param worker {ServiceWorkerGlobalScope} */(worker) => {

    worker.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
      // ...
    });

})(/** @type {any} */(self));
```

**[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoGMAWBTeBrAsAKBGAPAE7IBmyRAdvMqOQPawAmJAhgK4A2ks7AlgEYBeAESQCrZEOAA+bLlCESZZJWq9BQgO7I+G2gTRkhoadgAUwAFQWIAB2YFmAW1C79ZUAG8AymQBuPKgB1PQMCAHF2Wj5mdi94WhtkAF9QC2BTV1CASlABKU9sbFBilxCyADpmBgYAUV9lSAAZHmhIZTJTAHIeclaY9k6AGlBTZHrySBy8gqwSkrGG8o1mHkgAVQmediK54zASgD0Afh3ipKyAbkKsc-MrCEgAT0TPZnJHlLTTaGR2YizLkA)**

[image: Screenshot of the code above with code highlighting]