# What is the correct tsconfig.json for a service worker?

Tags: typescript, service-worker

Short version: TypeScript's `lib: ['DOM']` does not include Service Worker types, but `@types/service_worker_api` says it does.

I have a working TypeScript service worker. It has no problems other than I have to use `// @ts-nocheck` at the top of the file, because TypeScript can't handle the service worker types.

Similar to [TypeScript type definitions for ServiceWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172450/typescript-type-definitions-for-serviceworker), I originally followed the instructions to install the types for `service_worker_api`:

```
$ npm install --save @types/service_worker_api

npm WARN deprecated @types/service_worker_api@0.0.9: ServiceWorker types are now provided by '--lib dom'
```

So modifying my tsconfig accordingly:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "composite": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    // Resulting files will be in dist/service-worker.js
    "outDir": "dist",
    // From "@types/service_worker_api@0.0.9: ServiceWorker types are now provided by '--lib dom'"
    "lib": ["DOM"]
  },
  "include": ["src/service-worker.ts"]
}
```

This fails with:

```
$ npx tsc --project tsconfig.serviceworker.json
src/service-worker.ts(27,34): error TS2339: Property 'clients' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
src/service-worker.ts(51,8): error TS2339: Property 'skipWaiting' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

I also tried `WebWorker` - though I know WebWorker isn't quite the same as a service worker - and that fails with

```
src/service-worker.ts(66,56): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event'.
src/service-worker.ts(67,23): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event'.
```

**What is the correct `tsconfig.json` for a service worker?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting to help others in the same situation**

I found a lot of up to date information in Joshua T's blog post [Strongly Typed Web and Service Workers with TypeScript](https://joshuatz.com/posts/2021/strongly-typed-service-workers/).

- TS does indeed include service workers by default (see lib.webworker.d.ts)
- As Josh says:

> There are some big open issues with Web Worker types that are blocking easier solutions for strong-typing service worker files.

- [The definition for self is not resolved correctly](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14877)
- [Conflicts with DOM vs WebWorker](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20595)
- [Intersection of libs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11093)

Following 'Solution B: TSConfig Libs' - yes, use 'WebWorker':

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "composite": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    // Resulting files will be in dist/service-worker.js
    "outDir": "dist",
    // From https://joshuatz.com/posts/2021/strongly-typed-service-workers/
    "lib": ["WebWorker", "ES2015"]
  },
  "include": ["src/service-worker.ts"]
}
```

Note as VSCode only supports a single tsconfig.json for a project you may still need to add `@ts-ignore` to some lines.